# couldn't make regex search match a 10 digit number inside a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract some 10 digit numbers from a string using a regex on a python 3.7 script.

I have this regex that work pretty well when the number is the whole string:

```
^(?=.{10}$)((11|351|2267|)(\d+))
```

It matches ok whole numbers like *1153210611* or *3514681255*, but when I try to find numbers like this inside a string, like '*assd9**1153210611**83jdj*' it doesn't find it. I´m pretty sure it has to do with ^ and $ and a tried removing it or change their position without achieving success. When I remove ^ and $ it match but doesn't limit the length to 10 any more.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'^(?=.{10}$)((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', '1153210611')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='1153210611'>
>>> re.search(r'^(?=.{10}$)((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a1153210611b')
>>> re.search(r'(?=.{10})((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a1153210611b')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 11), match='1153210611'>
>>> re.search(r'(?=.{10})((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a115321061133b')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 13), match='115321061133'>
```

I need to extract 10 digit numbers that are composed by the initial digits with variable length of the first group and completed with digits from the second group. I have to add some other things next, like and optional +54 or a 54 before the number, like +541153210611 or 541153210611 but I don't want to continue without figuring out this first.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might use all 3 options and add the specific number of digits `(?:11\d{8}|351\d{7}|2267\d{6})` See https://regex101.com/r/WmKaxH/1

Comment: Just limit the _minimum_ 10 char's in the lookahead to digits `(?=\d{10})((11|351|2267|)(\d+))` If you only want 10 digits and no more, it is this `(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))`

Answer (score 0):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XUqGX3/1):

```
s = 'assd9115321061183jdj'

import re

print( re.search(r'2267\d{6}|351\d{7}|11\d{8}', s) )
```

Prints:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 15), match='1153210611'>
```

Comment: Hi mate! It's a great solution, very similar to what _the fourth bird_ has suggested. As I said to him, I tried to simplify the post with a few numbers but there are many more. I would prefer a solution similar to what _sln_ as posted if it is possible. Anyway I know now that this could be a solution if I couldn't make it work the other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The anchors `^` and `$` will assert the start and the end of the string. If you omit those, the `\d+` will match 1+ digits as much as possible.

The current pattern uses 3 capturing groups. If you are not referring to those groups in the code, you might use non capturing group `(?:` instead.

You could use each option and complement the number of digits to become 10 in total.

```
(?:11\d{8}|351\d{7}|2267\d{6})
```

If you want to prepend +54 or 54 you could add an optional non capturing group `(?:\+?54)?` to the pattern to match an optional `+` followed by 54

```
(?:\+?54)?(?:11\d{8}|351\d{7}|2267\d{6})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4a3Az/1)

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. Yes, that is correct, that would solve the issue perfectly. The thing is that there is many more numbers and not just these three. Sorry, I tried to simplify the post and I didn't realize that would be a problem later. I would prefer a way that I just tell it the length once if it is possible. Nevertheless it work perfect and is something I can use if I couldn't figure how to make it work the other way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Johannes The reason I went for this approach is that in for example this string `assd9115321061183jdj` you want the match to start with 11. In that case a boundary in front of it will prevent it to match. On the other hand, for every item you want exactly 10 digits, but there can be digits following after the 10 digits, so `\d+` will over match it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 10 digits and no more, it is this

`(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))`

https://regex101.com/r/5eXEld/1

Explained

```
 (?<! \d )                     # Not a digit behind
 (?=                           # Exactly 10 digits ahead
      \d{10} 
      (?! \d )
 )
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( 11 | 351 | 2267 | )         # (2)
      ( \d+ )                       # (3)
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Python

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', '1153210611')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='1153210611'>
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a1153210611b')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 11), match='1153210611'>
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a1153210611b')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 11), match='1153210611'>
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)(?=\d{10}(?!\d))((11|351|2267|)(\d+))', 'a115321061133b')
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I didn't expect an answer so fast! Thanks for that... This solution is great. Just one thing... How do I tune it up so re.search find this number 1153210611 in the last sample string 'a**1153210611**33b'?
Thanks for your time!